# how can I define a map accept different kind of value in thrift?

Tags: java, python, object, dictionary, thrift

I define a struct with thrift:

```
struct QuerySetRecord {
    1:string recordId,
    2:string crawlerName,
    3:string recordType,
    4:map<string,string> dataMap,
    5:i16 priority,
}
```

the problem is the `dataMap`, I do not only want to accept `string` value, I may still want to accept `List` or `Map`, such as `map<string, list<string>> dataMap`. In other words, I want a type like the root `Object` in Java, `object` in python

Can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to create your own `Object` and list all possible classes in it.

```
union Object {
   1: string str;
   2: i32 number32;
}
```

(as I'm not sure how union implementation works in all langs I'd go with struct with all fields optional)

```
struct Object {
   1: optional string str;
   2: optional i32 number32;
}
```

and then: `map<string, Object>`

In Thrift you can't create 'accept all' field, as it could not be fully portable across languages, and that's one of key functionalities of Thrift.